# How to position text within line using CSS?

Tags: html, css, formatting, position

I have two div's side by side, the text in the left div is just a little smaller then the text in the right div, but both have the same line height. How can I position the text in the left div up or down within the respective lines to make it line up better?

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/nhc84aLy/

```css
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  Name:
  <br> Age:
  <br> Occupation:
</div>
<div class="right">
  Kevin
  <br> 30
  <br> Engineer
</div>
```

Comment: Why not change the line-height until it aligns correctly? (Maybe you want a cleaner way of doing it...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to set its position to `relative` and then give it a top (or bottom) value.

```css
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 14px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  Name:
  <br> Age:
  <br> Occupation:
</div>
<div class="right">
  Kevin
  <br> 30
  <br> Engineer
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't that too far up?

Comment: I have no idea how far he wants it.  Its just an example ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `position` to `relative` in the `.left` div and the use the `top` attribute to move the block up or down.

```
.left {
    ...
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    ...
}
```